# the difference between 형용사 and adjective

Tags: grammar, adjective

if we search adjective in korean-english dictionary, the meaning of adjective is "형용사".
However, in Korean, afaik there is another "part of language" called "관형사", whose job is to qualify nouns.
Please explain about "형용사" and "관형사", and their similarity with adjectives. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both '형용사' and '관형사' describes '명사' (noun)
Technically, in Korea, '형용사' and '관형사' describes '체언' (noun, pronoun, numeral)
It is common thing between '형용사' and '관형사'
However, the difference between them is 'whether it is possible to be transformed' and 'whether it can be its position'

In Korea, 형용사 can be translated to 'adjective'.
It is 'similar' to English. (but, unfortunately, not perfectly same)

For example, adjective is usually related to noun such like 'It is a good book'
It can change its position and be predicative such like 'The book is good'

'형용사' is similar to this case. I would like to take '좋다'(good) 
For example, '형용사' is usually related to noun such like '이건 좋은 책이다'(It is a good book.)
It can change its position and be narrative such like '이 책은 좋다.'(The book is good)

But, in Korea, '형용사' can be 'transformed'. (bottom line!!) 
For example, the basic form '좋다' is transformed to '좋은'

Thus, '형용사' can be transformed. 
       '형용사' can change its position to describe noun like English.

However, '관형사' cannot transformed and change its position.
I would take again '이 책은 좋은 책이다.'
'이' belongs to '관형사'
'이' cannot change its form and change its location.
For example, 이 책은 좋다 (O)
             책은 이 좋다 (X)
             책은 좋다 이 (X)
             => It means '관형사' describes noun in front of 'NOUN'.
Also, Let's see '이건 좋은 책이다.'
'이건' can be disassembled to '이' + '것은'
'이' belongs to '관형어' and '것' means 'thing' or 'stuff'.

best regards.